# Using Jquery.parseJSON();

Tags: jquery, json

This is my code,

```
function responseLogin(response)
{
var newArray = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
alert(newArray.AccountEmail);
}
```

This is what is alerted,

```
{"AccountEmail":["Alphabets and numbers only","Alphabets and numbers only"]}
```

It has not been converted back to an array and i don't know why. I get the same result if i just use

```
alert(newArray);
```

Thanks

### **EDIT *_*__**

This is what i get after console.log

```
AccountEmail
["Alphabets and numbers only", "Alphabets and numbers only"]    
0
"Alphabets and numbers only"

1
"Alphabets and numbers only"
```

### **EDIT 2 *_*__**

if i use alert on the original response i get

```
[object Object]
```

Now i'm no expert at JavaScript but i don't think that is json.
This was the PHP used to generate it (which i have used before and it has worked)

```
echo json_encode($this->Account->invalidFields());
```

Comment: What does your original response data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited to match new question text*

If I run this statement in Firebug it works as expected:

```
alert(jQuery.parseJSON('{"AccountEmail":["Alphabets and numbers only","Alphabets and numbers only"]}').AccountEmail)
```

What it alerts:

> Alphabets and numbers only,Alphabets and numbers only

So I'd say there's something dodgy with your response argument. When you alert the response argument directly it claims to be an Object, but [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) requires a well-formed JSON string.

Try grabbing the [Firebug FF addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) if you don't have it already. Hit F12 to bring it up, activate the console panel, place a `debugger;` statement at the top of your function, and refresh the page. In the Firebug panel right next to the console is a "Watch" you can use to investigate what's inside the `response` variable by hovering/clicking on it.

Another thing to check: isn't the PHP script echo-ing anything else before/after the mentioned echo statement?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (=guess) that the source of the JSON has thrown an error due to the @ in the email - it's applying alphanumeric validation.

You have 2 emails, each with an '@' and "." which have failed validation. The validator instead of returning the original email address has instead passed "Alphabets and numbers only"

Your JavaScript is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm not keeping this numbers and letters only rule, i'm just testing the validation.